# Chrome: Specifying width on a div nested in a TD gives large right margin

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm specifying a div inside of a td tag. As soon as I specify the width of the div in pixels, in addition to that width Chrome shows a huge right margin and I don't understand why. I'm curious if anyone can help me make sense of this.

This js example shows the exact problem:

https://playcode.io/625077/

[image: Screenshot showing mysterious margin]

But with no width specified, there's no mysterious margin:
https://playcode.io/625261/

Also, there appears to be a ratio at play: for every 1 pixel of width that I specify on the div, I get several pixels of mystery right margin.

Update: even hard setting the margin and padding of the div to 0 seems to have no effect, leaving the remaining margin in place:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

All div has a default margin and padding. Your div inside a tb element is doing that. If you remove this div tag and let "test" stay just inside your tb element, the "test" string will touch the right side of the page.
Playing with the default tb style, you'll see that it tries to split the total width given (100%) equally between all tb elements inside a tr element. Doing so there is no space for a default div element which doesn't have this same property to be fit and also has a specific margin. The result of a div element inside a tr element is getting it longer than usual.

Comment: I don't think that's what's going on here. I updated the example in my question above to hard-specify margin and padding values of 0, and I still see the devtools showing what appears to be a large margin.

Comment: I hope now my answer solve your question. This was a good question for those who is studding CSS.